# Twine uploads too many packages to AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, python-packaging, aws-codeartifact

When uploading my HelloWorld package to AWS CodeArtifact, it also uploads all required packages to CodeArtifact. This causes several Gigabytes to be uploaded, which will cost me more money than it should. It also clutters the repository with packages I don't really care about.

I upload my package using twine: `twine upload --repository codeartifact target/dist/*/dist/*.tar.gz` (the target folder was generated with pybuilder and the wildcards are there because of the possibly changing version of my package).
I have also tried uploading the `.whl`, but that gives me the same result.

Here is an example of the packages uploaded to CodeArtifact:

[image]

The yellow marker marks the package I uploaded with twine. The unmarked packages just wanted to join the party I guess.

It is important to note that I have configured pypi as an upstream repository in CodeArtifact. So whenever installing a package that is not on CodeArtifact, it should find them on pypi.